# Error #410301 : Products not available between this origin and destination (network segment) for DHL in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, php, shipping, shipping-methods, dhl

> Error #410301 : Products not available between this origin and
>   destination (network segment) for DHL in Magento 2.3.2

Hi everyone.

I've a problem with DHL integration in Magento